# SQL - Ultimo Registro de cada carro

Tags: sql

Olá.

Estou consultando um BD onde retorna diversos dados de vários carros, que são coletados por um hardware instalado nestes. O hardware envia os dados a cada x segundos. Logo cada carro tem diversos registros. Precisava fazer uma query para buscar o ultimo registro (completo, todas as colunas) de cada carro. Como o banco não é meu podem ser inseridas ou removidas colunas.

Não tenho acesso ao id dos registros. Cada carro é identificado por um código 'vehicle_id' composto por uma letra e 3 números, ex: "A001". A forma que tenho para saber quando o registro foi enviado pelo hardware é por uma coluna 'date' que é armazenada no formato de milissegundos, ex: 1560776363000

Se eu não tiver sido claro por favor questione que tento explicar de outra forma.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola,

Você pode usar subquery apesar de isso não ter uma performance muito boa mas vai funcionar, qual o banco de dados?

```
select * from tabela A where campo_data = (select max(campo_data) from tabela B where A.vehicle_id = B.vehicle_id)
```

Comment: Não sei qual o banco. Envio a queri via API e recebo a resposta.

Comment: Tente fazer usando uma subquery então, seguindo o exemplo que eu coloquei acima..

Comment: Deu certo desta forma. Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função de agregação MAX:

```
SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(seu_campo_data) FROM sua_tabela GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado por sua resposta. Porém não deu certo. Como são diversos campos e preciso de todos n deu para usar a função MAX e em seguida *. E por conta do banco não ser meu, pode ser que sejam inseridas ou removidas colunas, tornando inviável colocar uma a uma.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função de agregação MAX:

```
SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(seu_campo_data) FROM sua_tabela GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

Caso necessite de mais campos de sua tabela então pode utilizar a query acima como uma subquery para identificar os registros a serem retornados, todos os registros identificados pelos pares de valores da subquery.

Comment: Seria algo do tipo: `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date), vehicle_id FROM cars GROUP BY vehicle_id)`. Obs: assim deu erro rs.